# Periodic re-keying during full drive encryption

Tags: brute-force-attack, 3des, performance

A man encrypted a hard drive in 1996 using three key 3-DES with a 64 bit IV and CBC mode in the following manner using known 1990s algorithms on a 1996 PC.  Here is how he did it.

Start with a randomly generated 256 character (full 0-255 range on each character) key generator.  Randomly generate a 64 bit IV in a separate manner, (not sure an IV is required in this scheme, except you should do everything you can to follow protocols).  Salt the 256 byte key generator with the IV and hash it with MD5 in order to produce the 128 bits that will provide the material for the first two 3-DES keys and then hash that result in order to use the first 64 bits of that hash as your third key.  Take your keys and your IV and encrypt the first 128 blocks of plaintext in CBC mode.  Then, re-key in the following manner.

Salt your original 256 byte key with all three keys and hash it with MD5 in order to produce the first 2 encryption keys and hash that result for your third key.  The last 64 bits of the second hash will be your IV for the next 128 blocks.

You repeat this pattern of re-keying every 128 blocks until the entire hard drive is encrypted.   When finished, you store the initial 64 bit IV and detailed instructions of how you encrypted the data in plaintext.

The question is, has this individual gained much security from periodically re-keying, as opposed to standard 3-DES for the entire drive?

You suffer two MD5 hashes of 280 bytes and a 3-DES key setup penalty every 128 blocks.  So far, this looks like a couple percent increase in drive encryption time at most.  The way I see it, it comes down to whether or not the suggested proposal provides enough additional security to justify the performance penalty.

Let's say an attacker acquires the ability to recover 3-DES keys 15, 20, or 30 years from now.  There is a typically a significant delay between the time an attack becomes practical and the time in which it becomes trivial.  For example, when DES keys were first brute forced, the attack was not trivial.  This could mean the difference between having to brute force a new key every 1 KB of that hard drive when it takes half an hour to do so, as opposed to recovering one key and decrypting the entire hard drive using the same key.

Comment: I believe it may get closed for being a "scheme analysis" question. I suggest you format your question based on background part, question part, and the part where you attempted solving. Also, use appropriate pronouns to correctly and consistently refer to the man with the encrypted disk, the cryptoanalisist, and the members of this Crypto.SE.

Comment: Rekeying would be a good idea if you're going to use a 64 bit block cipher for disk encryption. The 256 byte key is definitely overkill, MD5 is not a key derivation function, and the third key is generated in a weird way. That all said, I'll be danged if I'm going to attack that scheme, seems pretty solid to me. The main issue - as with most disk encryption - is seeing which blocks change in time. That could leak more information than you would like to assume. CBC is not a dedicated disk encryption scheme...

Comment: I tested performance using AES-128 and SHA-256 instead of 3-DES and MD5.  Re-keying every 1 KB was about 5% slower than simply using AES-128.  With DES, it was about 1% slower including the hashing and re-keying because 3DES is so much slower than MD5 and you are re-keying every 128 blocks, instead of 64 blocks with AES.